# How to show python call diagramm without evaluation?

Tags: python, documentation, documentation-generation

Say I have a folder with N files. An environment I can start my project from. Yet no tests to evaluate all the code I have. How to show python call diagramm without evaluation of all methods I have in py codebase?

Comment: What do you mean with "without evaluation of all methods".

Comment: not calling code explicitly, in other words, reading it, not running

Comment: You could probably run a documenter on it that also can create call / caller graphs. Doxygen can do this in a reasonable way giving which functions call which functions (thouhj not through things like what in C is called function pointer etc._.